# Redo of hardwood floors didn’t remove all poly

Tags: flooring, hardwood, hardwood-refinishing

I refinished my sunroom’s hardwood floors. It used to be an open porch. When I applied the poly, I noticed swirls and scratch marks and decided to redo them again. The floors are now even, polished and without swirls, but some streaks of the poly I applied a few weeks ago are still showing—though faint. Will I make a mistake if I apply new poly over them?

Comment: I think you already know the answer. You sound like a perfectionist or you wouldn't have redone it. you can concentrate on the areas with the streaks. If you don't, it will bug you every time you see it. The new poly will probably look a bit different over the existing streaks.

Answer (score 0):

At least complete a very light sanding and cleaning (400 grit or finer) or any imperfections will be magnified. As streaks I am guessing brush marks? This happens when poly is over worked. A light sanding and recoating can take out a lot of brush marks.

I regularly put down 3-4 coats and on things I want to look like glass many times that going up to 1200 grit, not a floor of corse but fine steel wool can also help but I prefer sandpaper when I want a true gloss.

Don’t overwork the poly put it down and don’t go back even 1 minute later or it may leave marks. Sanding and over coat hides brush marks but the surface needs to be prepped and multiple coats work even better.